# Is a sub query needed here SQL

Tags: sql

I am working on an assignment for school and I am slightly stuck. We are currently studying sub queries. But I am not sure that one is needed here. I am not looking for the full answer just a bump onto the right track of thought.

Here is the Question:

Write a SELECT statement that returns the name and discount percent of each Brand that has a
unique discount percent. In other words, don’t include Brands that have the same discount percent as
another Brand.
Sort the results by the BrandName column.

I know that I need to return the BrandName, and BrandDiscountPercentage from the Brands table, but is a sub query needed here? Of so why can I not just use the DISTINCT keyword. I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm still learning but I'm just not sure why a sub query is needed here.

Again, not looking for the full answer, although if you must supply the full solution please at least explain a little so I can actually learn from it.

Comment: can you show the table structure, sample data, and expected result?

Comment: Can't help without table structures and relationships

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags - MySql and SQL Server 2016 are completely different things and your task doesn't (and likely must not) require RDBMS specific functions.

Comment: You can't use distinct, you need a count of brands for each percent.  Use a subquery to find that count then join or use not exists to the brands table to eliminate them from the query.

Comment: @Filburt The site suggested MySql and im using the SQL 2016 software. Wasn't aware they are different. Sorry I hurt your feelings by "spamming tags"

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar Im sorry but what exactly do you need? Again rather new so not sure if there is an easy way to relay this information.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to `group by` the `BrandDiscountPercentage` and then filter out the duplicate values. The easiest way to show this is by walking through the steps.

**Select all query:**

```
select 
   BrandName, 
   BrandDiscountPercentage 
from Brands
```

**Results:**

```
BrandName   BrandDiscountPercentage
A           1       
B           2
C           3
D           2
```

---

**Group by BrandDiscountPercentage query:**

```
select BrandDiscountPercentage, count(*)
from Brands
group by BrandDiscountPercentage
```

**Results:**

```
BrandDiscountPercentage     count(*)
1                           1
2                           2
3                           1
```

---

**Filter out non unique BrandDiscountPercentage query:**

```
select BrandDiscountPercentage, count(*)
from Brands
group by BrandDiscountPercentage
having count(*) = 1
```

**Results:**

```
BrandDiscountPercentage     count(*)
1                           1
3                           1
```

---

**Include the BrandName by using an aggregate function query:**

```
select min(BrandName), BrandDiscountPercentage
from brands
group by BrandDiscountPercentage
having count(*) = 1
order by min(BrandName)
```

**Results:**

```
BrandName   BrandDiscountPercentage
A           1       
C           3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery or self join to achieve this.

1. You can select just the distinct discount percentage in a subquery and then retrieve the corresponding Brand name

   SELECT BRANDNAME, DIS_PERCENT
     FROM MyTable
   WHERE  (1,DIS_PERCENT) in (SELECT count(*), DIS_PERCENT 
                                FROM MyTable
                             GROUP BY DIS_PERCENT
                              HAVING count(*)=1)
2. Or can be a corelated subquery

   SELECT BRANDNAME, DIS_PERCENT
     FROM MyTable m
   WHERE 1=(SELECT count(*) from Mytable where DIS_PERCENT =m.DIS_PERCENT)
3. Or with a self join

   SELECT m.BRANDNAME, m.DIS_PERCENT
     FROM MyTable m, MyTABLE m1
    WHERE m.rowid<>m1.rowid 
      AND m.dis_percent<>m1.dis_percent
4. Select Distinct name, Discount_percent from table
   This will NOT work here, Because it will give the distinct combination of Brand and percentage. Your requirement will not be met "don’t include Brands that have the same discount percent as another Brand."

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not the right approach, because that returns all the values in the data once -- even if they repeat.

But, you don't actually need a subquery for this.  An aggregation query actually works:

```
select max(b.BrandName), BrandDiscountPercentage
from brands b
group by BrandDiscountPercentage
having min(b.BrandName) = max(b.BrandName);
```

This determines if there is more than one name for any given percentage.  If the `min()` and `max()` are the same, then there is only one value.  `Max(b.BrandName)` returns that unique value.

An equivalent `having` clause is:

```
having count(distinct b.BrandName) = 1
```